# The problem with the load of RAM in the virtual machine where it is installed MySQL

Tags: mysql, proxmox

**Schedule for Hour**

[image]

**Daily Schedule**

[image]

There is a virtual machine installed on the PROXMOX, MySQL is installed there.
For this VM allocated 30GB of RAM and 20 cores because it receives a lot of data.

The problem is that the load on the VM gradually increases, and I do not understand why.
After a reboot MySQL server, the data is processed very quickly, while the load on the RAM in the region of 3-4 GB.

After the server has been running for more than 24 hours, the data starts to be processed for a very long time, while the data arrive in the same amount.
The load on the RAM rises to 25GB.

What's wrong?
I attach a screenshot and `my.cnf`.

I'm sorry for my bad English.
Thanks for answers.

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
event_scheduler = on
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
language    = /usr/share/mysql/english
skip-external-locking
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 512K
thread_cache_size   = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections         = 700
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency      = 12
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 50M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 16
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=400M
innodb_log_buffer_size=80M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_log_file_size = 128M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
innodb_thread_concurrency = 12
sort_buffer=512M
thread_concurrency=32
#record_buffer=128M
query_cache_type=2
tmp_table_size=1G
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 0
log_slow_queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 10            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysql]
[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M
```

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner.pl (perl) report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: thank you! i post it in pastebin.com/EfhhQ8DD

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second=RPS - Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
key_cache_age_threshold=7200  # from 300 seconds to reduce key_reads RPS of 240123
thread_cache_size=100  # from 8 to reduce threads_created in 1 day
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G  # from 16G to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_reads RPS of 20
innodb_read_io_threads=64  # from 1 for improved read performance
innodb_write_io_threads=64  # from 1 for improved write performance
```

Please get in touch, there are many more opportunities available to improve your instance response time.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)
I will try these settings tomorrow.
Im am in UTC +3 hrs.

Comment: @LisB Bogdan, any feedback on the use of these suggestions?  Positive/Negative would be appreciated.